# All gnome native apps are not working on my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-apps

Most of my gnome Apps, like gnome-terminal, gedit, setting-centre... are not working after a system recommended software update on my 18.04.
Please help! no idea what to do since no terminal not text editor now!

BTW, other apps like Chromium, Firefox... are still working.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you based on the limited information you provide. We have no clue what is going wrong this way. My only recommendation at this point can be: reinstall.

Comment: found a log like this -> CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1

Comment: and when clicking on gedit icon, there is a seg fault like this:gedit[7251]: segfault at 2 ip 0000000000000002 sp 00007fff450c05b8 error 14 in gedit[5598148df000+2000]

Comment: AND: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

Comment: include all this information in your question. Also, try opening an ill behaving application in the terminal, and note the output in the terminal.

Comment: Since I couldn't launch my gnome-terminal, I went to the other console and install Terminator, and it works.And then I tried to launch gedit from command line in the Terminator, it works, gedit launched without problem, but I cannot cut text from gedit and paste it on web.

Comment: But when I tried to launch gnome-terminal via command line in the Terminator, it failed!
and it goes like this!
$ gnome-terminal
# Error creating terminal: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying.;   
And then I tried to launch settings via command line in the Terminator, a blank window popup, but still error like followings.   
$gnome-control-center
(gnome-control-center:1596): Clutter-WARNING **: 14:20:42.703: Whoever translated default:LTR did so wrongly。                   thanks you very much and please help!

Comment: And I found this in the syslog every couple second when I click the launch icon that never launch, Object St.DrawingArea (0x55840fb8a410), has been already deallocated - impossible to access to it. This might be caused by the fact that the object has been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs

Comment: I would probably reinstall without reformatting: this will preserve all of your user data and user settings. You you will need to reinstall your custom software, however (which will still find your preserved user settings). Will take you 30 minutes. Do this by selecting "something else" in the installer, indicating the partitions yourself and specifying they should not be reformatted.

Comment: Thank you very much, vanadium. I had tried to reinstall gnome-shell but no luck. Do you mean reinstall Ubuntu, like booting from .iso image? OK I will do this since it took me some days and still no idea how to solve it. Anyway, thanks a lot indeed!

Comment: Indeed reloading the installation ISO. If you select "something else", you have to indicate yourself what partitions are used for what. If you unselect "Format", the partitions will not be formatted again. As a result, the system files will be written out again, but your data will remain in place.